# FFMPEG to remove audio but keeping background sound

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add voice over to the existing video which has some audio in English and some background sound. I am trying to add other than English audio on top of it and keeping background sound. But when I add new audio it removes all the background sound and when it adds new audio which makes it robotic as original background sound is lost.
When I add new audio by using amix filter, it keeps all sound like English and new language both, and both plays together.

1. Is there any way to separate background sound and speaking audio from video separately?
2. Is it possible to mute or remove audio from only parts of video like offset between time frames?

Command that I am using for add new audio
`ffmpeg  -i independance_speech.mp4  -i 01.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000[s1];[s1]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v  -map "[a]" -c:v copy result.mp4`

Comment: 1. no, I think, is the correct answer, but you can study [all the available filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) yourself

Comment: 2. `volume` filter is the one that comes to my mind. it has timeline support so you can use `enable` option to control when to mute (if I understood your question correctly)